# Help required in triggers

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

CREATE TRIGGER membership AFTER INSERT ON jos_config5
FOR EACH
ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO jos_config4( identity_guid, UserID,
STATUS , original_conf_path, output_file_path, time_of_process, time_of_start, time_of_completion, status_message, Projectname )
VALUES (
'12', '345', '753', '34', '45', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'User has not started processing...', 'NA')

I am using the PHPMyadmin on executing the getting error as

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8

Regards,
Hemant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `BEGIN` with no `END`.  Try this instead:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER membership AFTER INSERT ON jos_config5
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO jos_config4 (
        identity_guid,
        UserID,
        STATUS,
        original_conf_path,
        output_file_path,
        time_of_process,
        time_of_start,
        time_of_completion,
        status_message,
        Projectname )
    VALUES (
        '12',
        '345',
        '753',
        '34',
        '45',
        'NA',
        'NA',
        'NA',
        'User has not started processing...', 'NA');
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

See here for the correct syntax:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: @hemant: It's not something I have ever tried, but you might find this useful: [Can triggers call SYSTEM?](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,170973,257815#msg-257815).

Comment: i trying this but gtting error as #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\! echo "php test.php?user="+ NEW.UserID + "&guid="+ NEW.UserID" >> /log/yourlog' at line 5